# how to save cost on non-production host servers running solarwinds appoptics agents

Tags: amazon-web-services, monitoring

I was monitoring 5 non-production servers during my initials deployment using appoptics host agent. Now, as production is live and monitoring it using appoptics APM so there is need to cut down monthly cost by stop monitoring for non-production machines.

But, I'm not getting any way to get rid of monitoring charges for 5 non-production machines. I will be happy if any one could help me through the process of saving cost here.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are basically two way of saving cost by removing host-agent from your machine.

1. Uninstalling the Agent
   For deb based systems:

$ sudo apt-get remove solarwinds-snap-agent

for RPM based systems:

$ sudo yum erase solarwinds-snap-agent

2.Uninstall Script:

$ sudo bash /opt/SolarWinds/Snap/support/before-remove.sh
$ sudo bash /opt/SolarWinds/Snap/support/after-remove.sh

The SolarWinds Snap Agent will be automatically removed from the Infrastructure Host view after 60 minutes.

Thank You!